# How to create a Sprite Color Mask in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the Among Us Spritesheets to get crewmates in Unity. The spritesheet looks like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/AmongUs/comments/ir6nl0/main_player_sprite_sheet_for_those_who_wanted_it/

Each sprite is a blue/red color.  Somehow the devs get every color of crewmate from these sprites, and I'm wondering how they did it.

How can I get every color of crewmate from this sprite sheet?

Thanks!

EDIT: Solution

I edited the title to be more accurate to my problem.  Thanks to @G Kalendar for mentioning Shaders, I hadn't thought about that.

What I ended up doing was creating a Shader Graph, extracting each color channel, multiplying it by a color value, and recombining them into a texture.

I followed this helpful and straightforward tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dAGUxvsD24

This is what my Shader Graph ended up looking like:
[image: Shader Graph for Among Us Color Mask]

"Secondary" and "Primary" are color properties.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: There are different ways to solve this, so it's hard to give a correct answer without looking at your whole project/context. But what you are probably looking for is [shaders](https://youtu.be/SQjeNhTp_Xg).

Comment: @Kaynnc and MickyD, thanks for the feedback.  I wasn't entirely sure how I wanted to solve this, but you're probably right, I could have been more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have multiple info stored in a single image, it's common practice to use the channels: Red, Green, Blue. Horizon Zero Dawn for example uses that technique to make the environment effects as efficient as possible.

Here it looks like blue and red are used as a polaceholder to mark an area. So in unity's shader graph, when you use this image in a SampleTexture2D node you can use a Split node to get the different channels of the image to isolate the parts you want to color in.

Then just multiply the different channels by the color you want, add them together and use that as the base color.

Edit: Or use the "Replace Color Node" I just learned about.

Comment: Compute Shaders were the answer! I edited my question to include what I did.